# Configuring Microsoft Outlook to read mails that are sent by local smtp server

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Is there any way I can configure my MS Outlook to read mails sent through local SMTP server. I am using hMailServer in the localhost.

Comment: What is the server delivering to?

Comment: I tried to send an email through a Java program to an id in gmail. It bounced with error. I have posted a question for that here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912478/problem-with-configuring-hmailserver/6912531#6912531)

Comment: Your server is misconfigured.

Comment: Any pointers to how to fix it?

Comment: No; I don't know anything about hMailServer.  Check the documentation.